# BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS

Tags: xubuntu, 19.04, iwlwifi, 19.10

I updated from 18.04 and run Xubuntu specifically. I updated to 19.04 and my wifi works and everything but for some strange reason for a few weeks now, no matter what I do, I cant get rid of this error.

It pops up in the quick black screen that appears before my login prompt shows up.

No matter what I cannot find anything to fix it, my wifi still works but that error appearing drives me up the wall.

```
iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

If you want specifics, there's the whole thing from the logs.

Comment: Its been a while were you able to find a fix for this?

Comment: Still _afflicts_ 18.04.4 LTS version (kernel 4.15.0-1073-oem). Hints: [here claimed bug](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/64703), with [a solution](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=243878), using [this resource](https://gist.github.com/mauron85/f764c88d2dc47af157487a7a318dd35b) unloading and reloading kernel modules pre and post suspend...

Comment: I am seeing the same error with Ubuntu 20.04 on my Asus F571GT laptop with Intel AX200 wifi. But the wifi does work fine! So maybe we can ignore the message, like I found suggested in forums too?! I just wonder then why it is flashing on the screen if it is not a failure or error. Also I wonder if we can add some WRDS or switch it off since it does not work…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS, Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155112/bios-contains-wgds-but-no-wrds-ubuntu-19-04)

Answer (score 6):

Found this message in a fresh Lubuntu 18.04.3 64 bit installation + latest updates
(5.0.0-27-generic kernel).
I can reproduce it doing:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
cat /var/log/syslog | grep iwlwifi
```

The system works fine (include wifi connections).

It seems to be a not important warning. At https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=243922 it says:

> *after the fix is applied contains the output "BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS"*

Answer (score 5):

We've got the same problem, seems to be from the Kernal update 5.0.0-27 as stated from Bellera. It could also probably be a wpa_supplicant issue.

Our system seems to hold at that message for a few seconds on boot, which drives me insane. Hope it will get fixed in the next update.

Its suspected that this primarily happens on Windows dual boot systems. We have switched from Windows to Linux on this device yesterday, which means we can't fix this issue ourselfs.

But it has been reported that booting up Windows and disabling the WLan from there than shutdown and boot into Linux, there should be no message about this anymore.

Maybe this helps you. If somebody knows where to report this to get this seen by Linux Kernel people, that would be great because I really cant find my way around all these repos tbh.

Comment: FWIW this happens to us on freshly-imaged Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) only devices.

Comment: This happens to me on latest, up to date 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for [BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS, Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155112/bios-contains-wgds-but-no-wrds-ubuntu-19-04), the duplicate of this question:

[Bug 205513 - iwlwifi: Change log level of "iwlwifi 0000:6f:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS" to "info"](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205513) has been fixed in Linux kernel.

From the ticket:

> We have investigated the issue and it turns out that the reference
> implementation of the BIOS recommends having WGDS set to NOP values
> when WRDS is not included.  This is what is causing the problem in so
> many platforms.  The error message itself is harmless, so I'm going to
> reduce the logging level as suggested.