# BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS, Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: suspend, 19.04, iwlwifi

I have been getting this weird error when I put my laptop to sleep and then waking it up after a while. This error forces me to force reboot my computer in order to restart my computer. However wifi and ethernet works fine so I am not sure why this error appears. It usually appears when I put my laptop to sleep and then leave the network then reopening it in my home using my home network.

When I last checked this error is from `iwlwifi`. Below is the return from the command `dmesg | grep iwlwifi`

My wifi card is Intel Ac 9560

```
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
```

[image: command output]

Comment: Same warning with Lubuntu 18.04.3 64 bit installation + latest updates (5.0.0-27-generic kernel) More at ...
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147801/bios-contains-wgds-but-no-wrds/1174694#1174694

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147801/bios-contains-wgds-but-no-wrds)

Comment: Still _afflicts_ 18.04.4 LTS version (kernel 4.15.0-1073-oem). Hints: [here claimed bug](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/64703), with [a solution](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=243878), using [this resource](https://gist.github.com/mauron85/f764c88d2dc47af157487a7a318dd35b) unloading and reloading kernel modules pre and post suspend...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bug 205513 - iwlwifi: Change log level of "iwlwifi 0000:6f:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS" to "info"](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205513) has been fixed in Linux kernel.

From the ticket:

> We have investigated the issue and it turns out that the reference
> implementation of the BIOS recommends having WGDS set to NOP values
> when WRDS is not included.  This is what is causing the problem in so
> many platforms.  The error message itself is harmless, so I'm going to
> reduce the logging level as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you ensure that your motherboard firmware is current. Since you have not specified what make or model of machine you are using, I cannot tell you where to find it or what version is current.

Answer (score 0):

As was correctly noticed by @pba, that's not critical bug caused by improper logging level. If your Wi-Fi works properly then there's no need to worry. I have got the same Wi-Fi card which runs in Kubuntu 20.04 without issues, despite these messages on boot and shutdown.
If these annoying messages spoil quiet booting and wake-ups then you can adjust console logging level. Run `cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk`, it will show you four numbers which represent current log levels (mine showed `4 4 1 7`). These numbers are explained in details in `man 2 syslog`. First number represents `console_loglevel`, we'll decrease it. Create file, say, `20-loglevel.conf` in `/etc/sysctl.d/` with contents:

```
kernel.printk = 3 4 1 7
```

Reboot and see that no more complaints regarding WGDS are shown.

**N.B.** You'll miss warning messages in console in this case, but more severe errors will be shown. This affects only warnings shown in console — all suspended warning messages are collected and remain in `dmesg` output.

Answer (score -1):

I had same error,

you can fix it by disable `nouveau` from the rescue mode with same USB bootable and install graphics card driver
and install WiFi driver then update grub, and it will boot normally

Comment: Can you give some details?

Comment: there are 3 steps there but not clear at all

Comment: please elaborate why WiFi and GPU are in some relation for this topic.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a problem with wpa_supplicant that is superceded by iwd that Intel opensourced, further information [here](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-IWD-1.6-Released). I have tested this with Buster 10, I hope someone of you can test it with latest Ubuntu OS. Below it is illustrated how it works in Debian.

*Partial solution*

```
 sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

where you can get the WIFI back, without actually solving the problem.

*Upgrade from wpa_supplicant to iwd*

```
#OS
#No LSB modules are available.
#Distributor ID:    Debian
#Description:   Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
#Release:   10
#Codename:  buster
#
#KERNEL 
#Linux hhh 5.4.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.4.19-1~bpo10+1 (2020-03-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux


#cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
#
#[main]
#plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
#
#[ifupdown]
#managed=false
#
#[wifi]
#wifi.backend=iwd

# Run the below after updating the script above.
#
#iwd instead of wpa_supplicant
systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
systemctl stop NetworkManager.service wpa_supplicant.service
systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

Comment: There are explanations for ubuntu in https://blobfolio.com/2019/10/replacing-wpa-supplicant-with-iwd-in-ubuntu-eoan/

Answer (score -1):

your're gonna want to (2) do something like this:

```
According to the bash man page, $RANDOM is distributed between 0 and 32767; that is, it is an unsigned 15-bit value. Assuming $RANDOM is uniformly distributed, you can create a uniformly-distributed unsigned 30-bit integer as follows:

$(((RANDOM<<15)|RANDOM))
Since your range is not a power of 2, a simple modulo operation will only almost give you a uniform distribution, but with a 30-bit input range and a less-than-16-bit output range, as you have in your case, this should really be close enough:

PORT=$(( ((RANDOM<<15)|RANDOM) % 63001 + 2000 ))
Share
Edit
Follow
```

Comment: no thatsawrong idea way . never—mind