# IWLWIFI halts boot on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, kubuntu, 20.04, iwlwifi

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04. I installed some updates suggested by Discover software center. After rebooting my system hangs and output the following:

```bsh
[   5.424291] iwlwifi 000:00:14.3 BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

I can get into TTY by pressing `ctrl` + `alt` + `f1`, and then login using my credentials. Once I'm in I can start everything normally by running `startx`.

I have to do this every time I boot though. Is there any way to:

1. Find out what's causing the boot to hang?
2. Revert the update caused by Discover?

I'm no Linux expert, so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this further. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: have a look at this https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=243922 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155112/bios-contains-wgds-but-no-wrds-ubuntu-19-04 https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/glufvi/iwlwifi_bios_contains_wgds_but_no_wrds/

Comment: @kannzzmm2 thanks for your response, but those two links don't seem to be relevant here. The first link has the solution as _renaming an SSID_, but this issue happened after an update and everything was working fine. There have been no network changes (in fact I've only ever connected to one wifi network from this machine). The 2nd link suggests installing `firmware-iwlwifi` and `firmware-linux, neither of which are available on my Kubuntu machine. Again, this issue started after an update was installed, i.e. new packages added to my machine, not removed.

Comment: I have the same error when I run dmesg on my Laptop running Ubun tu 20.04 LTS. In my opinion I dont think that this causes the boot to hang up, but to be sure you can remove quiet splash from /etc/default/grub and then sudo update-grub. Restart and check which service is taking more time and make a photo if possible and then edit your question..

Comment: I've moved on from Kubuntu now so I'm not faced with this error anymore. If someone else reading this is facing this issue, follow the steps suggested by @kannzzmm2 and either add a comment or edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to a wrong runlevel. I reverted it by running:

```
systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

More details in [Boot systems into different targets manually - RHCSA Objective Preparation](https://linuxconfig.org/boot-systems-into-different-targets-manually-rhcsa-objective-preparation)

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing! I don't have Kubuntu installed anymore, so I can't test this. But I'll mark this as the answer if it receives a decent amount of upvotes.