# WI-FI loses packets and connection is degraded after opening chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I Noticed a massive delay when i try to open any site, even the router page. I tried to debug "literally" the issue as following:

1. I pinged my router via `$ ping 192.168.1.1` and their was too many peaks and valleys with loss of 10%!.
2. I opened windows to ping the router but it was steady and their was never any spikes or packet loss.
3. I opened linux in rescue mode and pinged the router again and surprisingly the result was same as windows!
4. I tried to turn-off wifi power management via the following `$ iwconfig` and i obtained the wifi card name then I turned it off via `$ sudo iwconfig wlp0s20f3 power off`. Nothing nearly changed.
5. I got confused and I though that my laptop is being spoofed or hijacked when it connects to internet so I watched the internet usage using `gnome-system-monitor` but it revealed no internet traffic.
6. I turned off my VPN program (expressvpn) via `$ systemctl mask expressvpn.service` but the issue remained.
7. What I noticed is that, when I open google-chrome, the ping issue appears and when I entirely kill google-chrome, the ping returns back to normal just like windows or linux-rescue or even my phone!
8. Tried to check chrome task manager and there was nothing downloading/uploading.
9. Closed all tabs entirely so that chrome is opened on home and the issue remained.
10. tried reinstalling google chrome but to no avail.

I am 100% sure that there is a correlation between both and 99% sure that chrome is the cause for the massive packet loss and very high latency (9000 ms on average compared to 4 ms when it is closed).

No matter what time I give google, but the issue remains unresolved as if it is itself is making very high traffic.

My laptop is Lenovo Y530 with wifi card `Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)`. I updated the BIOS from 2 to 5 months ago (cannot recall specifically) and i found in `$ dmesg` this error `BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS` which is addressed in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155112/bios-contains-wgds-but-no-wrds-ubuntu-19-04).

Update 1 (3/11/2021):

```
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp7s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:6a:64:0b:4e:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:1d:ea:5e:25:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1350 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 500
```

Comment: What's your MTU? Check your WiFi `MTU`, using  `ip link` or `ip l | grep $(ip r | awk '/default/ {print $5}' ) | awk '{print $2, $4, $5}'`. Also read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: `$ip link`:


1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp7s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:6a:64:0b:4e:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:1d:ea:5e:25:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: `sudo jornalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`:

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: @OmarShawkey You have a typographical error. It's :`journalctl`", not "`jornalctl`".

Comment: @waltinator
1. sorry for these issues, indeed won't repeat them and will update the question as requested.
2. what type of typographical error?

Comment: @waltinator i ran the command and it ran successfully however, it is a 250 line of output; should i put it in my original question? i ignored to put dmesg output for the same reason (12k line). Extremely sorry if i caused you any confusion or trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was two solutions to such problem:

1. Contact Intel regarding your product and they will solve it for you.
2. The issue was due to a very similar WiFi Bandwidth nearby and the solution was to simply restart the router as the issue turned out to be from it despite that the issue was with a single device only.