# Frozen after rebooting (upon upgrading to 20.04 from 18.20)

Tags: wireless, upgrade, 20.04, bios

I can only see the black screen with:

```
1.407977 iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIoS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

I am using dual boot (Windows & linux)
I have updated ubuntu to 20.04. After updating I found that there are 6 packages that are upgradable. I have manually updated few of them (didn't remember the packages name). In order to update the remaining packages, some of the existing packages need to be deleted. Post installation of the 6 packages. I have updated the desktop and rebooted the system.

Firing the laptop opening with a black screen and the below line of statement:

```
41.407977 iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIoS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147801/bios-contains-wgds-but-no-wrds)

Comment: @ Marcus I have tried this but none f the these solution are working