# BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS: what's happening?

Tags: networking, 20.04

I have issues with my wifi connection on ubuntu 20.04. It disconnects randomly only with my home wifi. I'm kinda getting mad after this issue, thus I am trying to monitor everything I can in order to find possible causes to this issue.
I ran `sudo dmesg` and I found at the very beginnig of which seems a log of my connection activities, the following message:
`BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS`.
Can anyone explain me what is it? Can it be related to the connection issues I am facing? I don't even know what WGDS and WRDS are.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147801/bios-contains-wgds-but-no-wrds)

Comment: No, because I'd like an explanation of what exactly mean WGDS and WRDS. Please don't strike my question since it's slightly different to the one quoted

Comment: This message is not related to your problems. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: The output is ```00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW) [8086:34f0] (rev 30)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW) [8086:0234]
 Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
 Kernel modules: iwlwifi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:34e8] (rev 30)
``` I post this as a comment because I don't want to go too much out of topic

Answer (score 0):

Example of output of `sudo dmesg | grep WRDS`:

```
[    4.803894] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
[ 3323.493255] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
[ 4427.419793] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

This message is related to information stored in the BIOS about the wifi device; It seems that WGDS and WRDS are related to geolocation and radio transmission power limitations.

The message sometimes appear during boot or, in some cases upon coming back from a sleep state, depending on the BIOS implementation. <sup>[source](https://superuser.com/a/1547259/)</sup>

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. I don't know why I couldn't find your source online before!

Comment: @HubOne If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.