# ACPI BIOS Error (bug) - Ubuntu - BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS

Tags: boot, suspend, iwlwifi, acpi

> Failure creating named object [SB.PCIO.R P07.BRST), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS
> (20221020/dswload2-326) t 0.648135] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS,
> During name lookup/catalog (202210 20/psobject-220) 0.648150) ACPI
> BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object (_SB.PCIO.R P07.RSTX),
> AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dswload2-326) 0.648161) ACPI Error:
> AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202210 20/psobject-220)
> 0.648185) ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object _SB.PCIO.R P07.RSTG), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dswload2-326) 0.648194) ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202210 20/psobject-220) [ 0.648262) ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure
> creating named object (_SB.PCIO.R P07.PXSX.L850], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS
> (20221020/dswload2-326) 0.648272) ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS,
> During name lookup/catalog (202210 20/psobject-220) [ 0.648288) ACPI
> BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object SB.PCIO.R P07.PXSX.
> RST), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dswload2-326) 0.648297) ACPI Error:
> AE ALREADY EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202210 20/psobject-220)
> /dev/nvme0nip2: clean, 297214/31227904 files, 9498211/124895488 blocks
> [ 3.547407) iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS

The error pops up for a couple seconds before starting, overall everything works fine. Just wondering how to fix it)

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1489905/acpi-bios-error-bug-ubuntu you are using debian occording to the previous topic.  Plus it has been said before a few times: "ACPI BIOS Error (bug) -" is not an issue.  See for instance https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416198/ubuntu-22-04-acpi-bios-error-bug-could-not-resolve-symbol-errors-on-asus-x7    "BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS" https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296345/bios-contains-wgds-but-no-wrds-whats-happening   ALL of these are not issues for us users. Those are for kernel developers and hardware manufacturers to fix.

Comment: "overall everything works fine" so there is no problem...